# Can patents be searchable by number?

Tags: discussion, search

Is there a syntax to be used when searching for patents on AskPatents?  For example this [answer](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/307/906) to the popular Apple V Samsung question, contains multiple references to the cases associated patents.  Now these link to Google Patents, and that's fine.  However if your coming from Google Patents, and you want to search the site by patent number then this doesn't seem possible.

Again, the [answer](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/307/906) refers to abbreviated US patents.

> '381 "rubber-banding" patent: Yes for all devices.

Now taking the full patent number from the [Google Patents](http://www.google.com/patents/US7469381), US7469381.  I can't search AskPatents for any other related material.  The following search terms return nothing except the last entry [2012/09/21 14:35 GMT];

US7469381

7469381

381 * this is too ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most questions should be tagged appropriately. For instance, questions about US7469381 should be tagged with [us7469381](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us7469381). The question is... should [Which patents were involved in Apple v. Samsung?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/306/345) be retagged appropriately?

Comment: Agreed, they should be listed in full.  I have editing to be done!

Comment: I think there's a limited of 5 tags though...

Comment: Crickey, that's not enough.

Comment: See http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/q/56/345

Comment: That's the answer I was after, thanks.